# If $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are three distinct complex numbers satisfying

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$\frac{3}{|z_2-z_3|} = \frac{4}{|z_3-z_1|}=\frac{5}{|z_1-z_2|}$$ Find the value of $$\frac{9}{|z_2-z_3|}+\frac{16}{|z_3-z_1|}+\frac{25}{|z_1-z_2|}$$

Let The given equality be equal to some value k
Then $$9=k^2|z_2-z_3|^2$$ and so on

Replacing these values 
$$k^2[|z_2-z_3|+|z_3-z_1|+|z_1-z_2|]$$ How should I solve further? The minimum value can be calculated to be zero, but the question is asking for the actual value.

Comment: Obviously $12k$, but $k$ could be any positive number.

Comment: @MartinR Now, that's a much better question!